# Email is not sending code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm having a big problem with code igniter emails. When i'm working localhost the email is normaly send by smtp protocol, but when i up to the server the mail sending is not working.

My mail configurations :

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.duplov.com.br';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';
        $config['smtp_user']= '**********';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '***********';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline'] = '\r\n';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

Detail tha stmp_pass and stmtp_user i just hide.
My send email code :

```
public function validacao(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome','Nome','required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone','Telefone','required|min_length[13]',array('min_length' => 'Você precisa colocar um telefone válido incluindo o DDD'));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mensagem','Mensagem','required|min_length[20]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $erros = array('mensagens' => validation_errors());
            $jsonStr = json_encode($erros);
            echo $jsonStr;
        }
        else{
            if($mensagem = $this->enviar_mensagem($this->input->post('nome'),$this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('telefone'),$this->input->post('mensagem'))){
                $sucesso['mensagens']   = 'sucesso';
                $jsonStr = json_encode($sucesso);
                echo $jsonStr;
            }else{
                $sucesso['mensagens']   = $this->email->print_debugger();
                $jsonStr = json_encode($sucesso);
                echo $jsonStr;
            }
        }
    }

    public function enviar_mensagem($nome,$email,$telefone,$mensagem){
        $this->load->model('funcoes');
        $this->funcoes ->contato($nome,$email,$telefone,$mensagem);
        $emails = $this->funcoes->get_infos();
        foreach ($emails as $em){
            $this->load->library('email');
            $dados['nome'] = $nome;
            $dados['email'] = $email;
            $dados['telefone'] = $telefone;
            $dados['mensagem'] = $mensagem;
            $mensagem = $this->load->view('email/template',$dados,true);
            $this->email->from("no-reply@duplov.com.br","Gerenciador do website");
            $this->email->to($em->email);
            $this->email->subject('Contato site');
            $this->email->message($mensagem);
            return $this->email->send();
        }
```

The error i'm getting :

```
220-a1-caju27.servidorwebfacil.com ESMTP Exim 4.89_1 #1 Thu, 05 Apr 2018 11:44:31 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
hello: 250-a1-caju27.servidorwebfacil.com Hello oestedeminas.cphost0027.servidorwebfacil.com [200.98.245.32]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-CHUNKING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Incorrect authentication data
It is not possible to send e-mail using PHP SMTP. Your server may not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Comment: Well, the error states: _"Incorrect authentication data"_. It's pretty hard for us to know why that happens (if you're sure you've entered the correct credentials) considering that we know nothing about the mail server.

Comment: FYI: there is a non-English description in the error message. Probably a good idea to give us the translation, because people might be able to help but won't be willing to manually paste it in a translator.

Comment: did you checked using smtp protocol ? here you using mail protocol in email.php config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `$config['protocol'] = 'mail';`

Are you using the right protocol? Try changing to `$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';` Make sure you enter the right smtp details and the outgoing port isn't blocked on your server too. Try another smtp server or test it again locally using [MailSlurper](https://github.com/mailslurper/mailslurper), just to confirm.

You can read more on email preferences [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences).

Comment: yeah, i put it here incorrectly. i tried to use both in $config['protocol'] but anyone is working